# Bibliography in Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, bibliography

I'm trying to insert a bibliography for a research paper in Microsoft Word 2010. I'm using manage sources in the references toolbox to insert my sources. Word is formatting my sources the way I want them but, when I insert the bibliography it is always in alphabetic order.

I want to insert the bibliography so that the papers are in the order I cite them in the paper for example,

A sentence in my  paper could end like this,

> as can be seen in [1] and [2] among others.

I would then like the Bibliography to look like this,

> #### References
>
> [1] Morris, J., and S. Johnson. "Discrete Element Modeling." Journal of Geotechnical and Geoenvironmental Engineering (American Society of Civil Engineers), 2007.
>
> [2] Kruggel-Emden, H., M. Sturm, Wirtz S., and Scherer V. "Selection of an appropriate time integration scheme for the discrete element method(DEM)." Computers and Chemical Engineering 32 (2008): 2263-2279.

However, I can't get the bibliography to stop inserting the references in alphabetic order. I know how to get the brackets and the numbers outside the references as shown above but, I don't know how to get the references in non-alphabetic order.

I have tried assigning numerical tags to each of the references in the manages sources section but, that did not work. Does anyone have any idea how to do this? I do not want to write out all the sources myself or sort the sources at the end with the function in the table menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Microsoft Word 2010, Bibliography Styles are **managed via XML template files**.

### It is not easy to change these files and you can damage your Bibliography function if you make a mistake.

1. Save your document and exit Word completely (`File -> Exit`)
2. Look for a template file with a name close to the Bibliography style you are using in the directory `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\Bibliography\Style`
3. Make a backup copy of that file and name it `unsorted.xml`
4. Open `unsorted.xml` in your favorite text editor
5. Remove the line that contains `<sortkey>` and `</sortkey>`
6. Search for the line that contains `<stylename>` and `</stylename>` and replace the style name between them with `unsorted`
7. Open your document in Word and **return to each of your citations** and change the style to `unsorted`

This [article](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-word/archive/2009/04/29/bibliography-citations-102-building-custom-styles.aspx) has information on how to update the template files but does not specifically address the sort-key. This [article](http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/sort-bibliography-alphabetically-author-word-2007/) has information on sortkey in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

A kind programmer has written and released an [open-source tool](http://bibword.codeplex.com/documentation) to manage Bibliography styles. It provides advanced formatting capabilities and automatic workarounds to overcome limitations in Word but it does not appear to provide an easy sort function.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer here isn't accurate based on my installation of Word 2010. The styles come in *.xsl files, not *.xml. And the tags `<sortkey/>` and `<stylename/>` don't exist in the default styles that come with Word (although StyleName does show up in some `<xsl:when/>` tags). I'm not sure why that discrepancy exists. But here's how I solved this issue.

Somewhere in your bibliography style, you'll find a template for the bibliography as a whole. You can insert an xsl:sort there. My custom style looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:b="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/bibliography">
    ... other stuff ...
    <xsl:template match="b:Bibliography"> 
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"> 
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select ="*">
                    <!-- Sort according to the order in which the sources are used in the document. -->
                    <xsl:sort select="b:RefOrder"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    ... other stuff ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`RefOrder` is the order in which they're cited. It's a tag that will exist regardless of whether it's defined in BIBFORM.XML (where source types such as Book or Website are defined).

The built-in APA style also uses xsl:sort but it's much more complicated. If you want to make a copy of an existing style, you will need to modify the `<xsl:when>` block that contains StyleName.